# Dinamically allocating a 2D matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to allocate a 2D matrix in C, that's already inicialized. I need it already inicialized to form the table of contents that will be used after for the next functions.

the matrix

```
char matriz2D[8][24] ={{'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#','\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '#'},
                            {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'}};
```

How i could allocate it? I am trying the code

```
matriz2D[alocador1][alocador2] =(char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

But the compiler throws me the error:

`error: assignment to 'char' from 'char **' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

How i can proceed to allocate in memory this matrix?

Comment: You cannot allocate a matrix that is already initialized, except for `calloc` to initialize memory to zero. `malloc` gives you uninitialized memory. You have to put data in it in a separate step. What do you mean that “trying to allocate a 2D matrix in C, that's already inicialized”?

Comment: It's because when i try to pass the matrix to a function, it throws me a memory out of bounds error, thus indicating that the matrix is not acessed by the matrix

Comment: @gustavomorettoitikawa "because when i try to pass the matrix to a function ..." --> Post that sample code.

Comment: The code of the functions as follows, i am trying to make a basic pathfinder function to later use, but the functions throw me a memory out of bounds when i try to use the data inside the matrix, like in the statement `if(matrix[element_positionY+1][element_position]!='\0')
        {
            printf("The cell above is clear!\n");
            return VALID_MOVEMENT;
        }else
            {
                printf("The position above is occupied!\n");
                return INVALID_MOVEMENT;
            }`

Comment: Read this: [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can not allocate dynamically an initialized array except that the function `calloc` can initialize the allocated memory by zeroes.

So at first you need to allocate memory for the two-dimensional array and then set its elements as required.

To allocate the matrix dynamically as a two-dimensional array you can write for example

```
enum { M = 8, N = 24 };
char ( *matriz2D )[N] = calloc( 1, sizeof( char[M][N] ) );

memset( matriz2D[0], '#', sizeof( matriz2D[0] ) );
memset( matriz2D[M-1], '#', sizeof( matriz2D[M-1] ) );

for ( size_t i = 1; i < M-1; i++ )
{
    matriz2D[i][0] = '#';
    matriz2D[i][N-1] = '#';
}
```

Pay attentfion to that instead of the magic numbers `8` and `24` it is better to use named constants. Also bear in mind that elements of the matrix do not contain strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write this. The way to go depends on the way you will use the area.

**First question to ask is if the matrix dimensions is always the same**

If `char[8][23]` is all you will need I will show you an example of a simpler way to write this.

Anyway you need to know that `char **` is another thing and must be constructed carefully, as `char ** **` is. These are very useful constructs but may be here you do not need them.

If your use case is for something more dynamic write back and I can post an alternative using `char **` or something else.

#### output of the example

```
Set 1 [ a b c d e f ]
Set 2 [ g h i j k l ]

allocating new area for matrix

copy set 1 to new area
In new area: [ a b c d e f ]

copy set 2 to new area
In new area: [ g h i j k l ]

free()'ing memory
```

#### Example `C` code

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char(Target)[2][3];
int print_set(Target*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Target set_1 = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}};
    Target set_2 = {{'g', 'h', 'i'}, {'j', 'k', 'l'}};

    print_set(&set_1, "Set 1");
    print_set(&set_2, "Set 2");

    printf("\nallocating new area for matrix\n");
    Target* pTarget = (Target*)malloc(sizeof(Target));

    printf("\ncopy set 1 to new area\n");
    memcpy(pTarget, set_1, sizeof(Target));
    print_set(pTarget, "In new area:");

    printf("\ncopy set 2 to new area\n");
    memcpy(pTarget, set_2, sizeof(Target));

    memcpy(pTarget, set_2, sizeof(Target));
    print_set(pTarget, "In new area:");
    printf("\nfree()'ing memory\n");
    free(pTarget);
    return 0;
};

int print_set(Target* tgt, const char* title)
{
    if (tgt == NULL) return -1;
    printf("%s [ ", title);
    for (size_t a = 0; a < 2; a += 1)
    {
        for (size_t b = 0; b < 3; b += 1)
            printf("%c ", (*tgt)[a][b]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The `typedef` is just for readability. `print_set()` is an example of how to pass the area as a whole.

Comment: That way worked the best for me! It was easier to implement and wrap around my head. Thank you so much!

Comment: The matrix will always be fixed, since it is only a canvas to visually represent two points in a 2D space

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it hard. Use a struct.

```
struct your_matrix_s {
   char matriz2D[8][24];
};
struct your_matrix_s *matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix));
```

Do not cast result of malloc.

If you are up for a challenge, then you might want a pointer to an array:

```
char (*another_matrix)[24] = malloc(8 * sizeof(*another_matrix));
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have allocated the matrix. Just not *dynamically*.

Given that this matrix is not prohibitive in size to have on the stack, the only reason you'd need to dynamically allocate would be if you're *creating* it within one function and need it to survive that function's lifetime.

Your question hints your problem lies in passing this to a function. When your matrix is passed to a function it decays to a pointer, but what kind of pointer? Well, it decays to a pointer to an array of 24 characters.

If you try to write the following, you will get warnings from your compiler and then in my testing, a segmentation fault.

```
void foo(char **m) {
    m[0][0] = 'A';
}
```

```
test.c:33:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char[8][24]' to parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    foo(matriz2D);
        ^~~~~~~~
test.c:3:17: note: passing argument to parameter 'm' here
```

But, if you write the following, then your function arguments are properly typed and it works as expected.

```
void foo(char (*m)[24]) {
    m[0][0] = 'A';
}
```

If you need to be able to pass matrices with different dimensions, we can pass a `size_t` argument as well.

```
void foo(size_t n, char (*m)[n]) {
    m[0][0] = 'A';
}
```

For your matrix, this would be called as:

```
foo(24, matriz2D);
```

Comment: Tried the arguments, but the compiler throws this error: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]|", and thus doesnt work.

Comment: The thing is, the problem occur when i try to pass the matrix to another functions